# How to write file stream in same file source

Tags: c#, filestream

I want to write FileStream with the SourceFileName, but when I created code to do so, an error message indicates that the file stream is being used. how to alternate so I open the source file and then write it down and then stored in the same source file. Thanks

> SourceFileName = output

Here is the code :

```
public void Encrypt(string SourceFileName, string output, string Key)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream FS1 = null; FileStream FS2 = null;
        FS1 = new FileStream(SourceFileName, FileMode.Open);
        FS2 = new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        byte[] input = new byte[FS1.Length];
        FS1.Read(input, 0, input.Length);
        byte[] Encrypted = Encrypt(input, Key);
        FS2.Write(Encrypted, 0, Encrypted.Length);
        FS2.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read and write the same file in that way.  You have two choices:

1. Read all the data in first before writing all the data out, with the processing somewhere in between.
2. Write out to a different file and then move it to overwrite the original file when you're done.

Comment: helped, but I need to make alternative code what you mean. Can you?

Comment: Sure I can, but that's not the point.  Can you?  I've told you what to do.  Now it's your turn to at least try to do it.  You don't know that you can't do it if you don't try.

Comment: Thanks. number 1. Can you show some code to implement it in my code ?

Comment: So, you're still not willing to make any attempt at all?  I guess you can go without then.  Make an effort and I'll help with any problems but I'm not here so that you don't have to make that effort.  The one more thing I will tell you is that the File class has methods to read and write the entire contents of a file in one go, so that might be the place to start.  That might be an issue for big files though, which is why I'd tend to go with option 2.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify sharing options when opening the file

`FS1 = new FileStream(SourceFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)`

Comment: I've tried it, but the message is 'stream does not support writing.'. Do you know where the problem?

Comment: Encrypt(input, Key); does not compile as it has 3 parameters actually.

Comment: While it is possible to read from and write to the same stream, you can't overwrite the data that you're supposed to be reading because then you will be reading the data that you just wrote instead of the original data.